# Confluence version history

Tags: versioning, confluence

It's nice to have a version history in Confluence. However a new version has been created every time when the document is edited and saved. I'm looking more for a "release" history. Assume I have version 1.0 of my document/page. Then I edit and save the page a couple of times before I'm ready with "release" 1.1. I need something to link a version to a release number and then have an automated release history.

Is there a way to do do something like that in Confluence?

Answer (score 9):

I guess **Scroll Versions** plugin from **K15t Software** could be one possible solution for versioning and release management of wiki pages within Confluence. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.scroll.scroll-versions

P.S. I know it is tad old question, but I think someone else may need this info.

Answer (score 3):

A method I have seen used is to attach a file to a page, change the document and upload with the same name multiple times, then change the link on the page when the version changes.

Usually a link to an attached document always references the highest version like this:

```
[^list.docx]
```

[ and ] mark the start and end of the link
^ to the right of [ refers to an attachment on the current page
and the rest is the name of the attachment
which resolves to a hyperlink of:

```
http://wiki.server.name/download/attachments/464233765/list.docx
```

From the page the full url is more specific:

```
http://wiki.server.name/download/attachments/464233765/list.docx?version=1&modificationDate=1406619789890
```

Refer to Tools > Attachments for a list of file version numbers.

Edit the page.

Create a link to the 'next' version with appropriate link text.

```
[list.docx V2.1|///download/attachments/464233765/list.docx?version=6]

[list.docx V3.0|///download/attachments/464233765/list.docx?version=9]

[list.docx V3.1|///download/attachments/464233765/list.docx?version=11]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote Confluence always creates a new version once an existing attachment is uploaded with the same file name as displayed on the attachment view.

> Existing files will be kept with the name 'Version x', where the value
>   of 'x' increments with each upload of an attachment with the same file
>   name.

Source: 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Attachment+Versions

This cannot be changed by configuration in Confluence.

However you can try [Arsenale Lockpoint](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.arsenale.plugins.lockpoint), which is a Confluence Add-on.

> Arsenale® Lockpoint™ is the enterprise standard for checkout, checkin
>   and controlled versioning of Confluence attachments...

Source: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.arsenale.plugins.lockpoint

- [Arsenale Lockpoint Documentation](http://www.arsenalesystems.com/support/arsenale-lockpoint?ref=px)

**EDIT**

- I have just installed and tested `Arsenale Lockpoint` and could not find the feature you are looking for
- I don't know of any other add-on that would meet your requirements
- Therefore i would recommend to edit the file locally and upload it only if you want a new version (release)

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative to other answers is to use change comments.

When editing page there is an input field next to save button at the bottom. This field has a placeholder "*What did you change?" and its content is shown in page history.

So you can edit page several times and when you want to "release" the version, you can fill the comment with release version. This way you can see all page versions in page history but you are able to easily identify the releases.

See [Confluence documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/confluence-user-s-guide/creating-content/using-the-editor/working-with-drafts/recording-change-comments)

Comment: The process of adding a new file does not involve editing the page.